# Registar número sequencial por ano PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu queria criar um registo de numeração automática mas que reset cada ano. Ficando por exemplo 170001...170002 e para o ano 180001...180002

Mas com este código fica me a registar sempre 1700001

```
<?php 
   function conectarBanco(){
      return new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bvmarco');
   }
   function primeiraOrdemAno(){
      return date('y'). '00001';
   }
   function novaOrdemServico(){
      $db = conectarBanco();
      $sql = 'SELECT max(Id) as `ultimo_id` FROM `participacao` WHERE year(data) = year(now()) ';

   $result = $db->query($sql);

   if($result === true){
      $ordem_servico = $result->fetch_assoc();
      return ++$ordem_servico['ultimo_id'];
   }else{
      return primeiraOrdemAno();
   }
   }
   $nova_ordem = novaOrdemServico();
?>

<input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nova_ordem ?>" required>
```

Com ajuda consegui fazer o código.
Quando precisarem fica aqui uma dica.

```
<?php
   function conectarBanco(){
      return new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bvmarco');
   }
   function primeiraOrdemAno(){
      return date('y'). '00001';
   }
   function novaOrdemServico(){
      $db = conectarBanco();
      $sql = 'SELECT max(Id) as `ultimo_id` FROM `participacao` WHERE year(data) = year(now()) ';
      $result = $db->query($sql);
      if($result === true){
         $ordem_servico = $result->fetch_assoc();
         return ++$ordem_servico['ultimo_id'];
      }else{
         return primeiraOrdemAno();
      }
   }
   $nova_ordem = novaOrdemServico();
?>
```

Comment: 170001 é referente a 2017 e 180001 é referente a 2018?

Comment: E se chegar a 179999 antes de virar o ano, o que acontece?

Comment: Correcto, o 17 no inicio refere 2017 e o 18 refere 2018

Comment: Ajudaria se pudesse [edit] a questão apontando a dificuldade encontrada.

Comment: queria que aumenta-se para 1710000

Comment: O registo efectuado é sempre o mesmo

Comment: Se vale a pergunta, tem como descrever o motivo de você necessitar um valor assim? Por favor, responda isso editando a pergunta, não nos comentários. Inclua, também, os detalhes dados nos outros comentários. Toda e qualquer informação da pergunta deve estar na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em SQL puro dá para obter o próximo serial assim:

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(
      YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) % 100,
      LPAD( COALESCE( MAX(serial_do_ano), 0 ) + 1, 4, '0' )
   ) AS serial
FROM
   tabela
WHERE
   YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) = YEAR(data)
```

Provavelmente deveria ser desnecessário dizer, mas você precisa inserir o ID no banco, para que o próximo seja incrementado, obviamente.

Pontos de interesse:

- `CONCAT`:  une vários valores em uma *string* só;
- `LPAD`:  complementa os zeros à esquerda do `id`;
- `COALESCE`:  escolhe um valor *default* caso seja nulo o `ìd` (o primeiro do ano).

No caso, usamos `4` no LPAD. Se quiser que o número de casas não seja limitado, pode adaptar com um `IF`, mais ou menos assim:

```
IF( valor > 9999, valor, LPAD( valor, 4, '0' ) )
```

Comment: Mas eu queria que produzi-se um algoritmo sequencial

Comment: É exatamente o que o código acima faz. É claro que precisa inserir o ID novo no banco, senão fica parado né... Ele sempre gera um ID novo baseado no anterior.

Comment: o resultado que sai é 171700

Comment: @Everson grato pela intenção, mas com autoincrement não dá para fazer o que o autor quer. Tem que inserir o ID anterior junto, senão dá problema na virada do ano (não vai voltar para final 0001), por isto removi seu fiddle. Depois, se eu tiver um tempinho livre, complemento com um exemplo funcional e explico melhor. De qualquer forma, grato novamente..

Comment: aonde vou colucar o codigo{IF( valor > 9999, valor, LPAD( valor, 4, '0' ) )}

Comment: @AdelinoVasconcelos recomendo nem usar o IF, foi só um exemplo caso passe de 9999. O que pode fazer é o seguinte, aumentar o numero de casas com zero (trocar o 4 por 5 ou mais) assim seu número fica com quantidade igual de dígitos.

Comment: Ah, e sobre o 171700, ao armazenar, não ponha o 17 do ano no DB, apenas o 0001 0002 etc. - O ideal no seu caso inclusive é não armazenar o ano junto do serial, melhor seria guardar na tabela só a data + 0001, data + 0002 e pegar o "17"."0001" na hora do select ou na própria aplicação. Fica mais simples, ocupa menos espaço. Para proteger sua aplicação de inserções inválidas e agilizar a busca, pode fazer um INDEX pegando ANO + SERIAL